# flattening nested dict type json file

Tags: pyspark

We are trying to flatten a nested json with below format :

```
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "5b37cfab-8a88-5609-b179-93f87126030a",
  "SequenceNumber" : "10000000000000010000",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:956978673417:de-eec-org-group-association-info.fifo",
  "Message" : "{\n\"messageType\": \"NEW_USER_ASSOCIATION\",\n\"messageStatus\": \"SUCCESS\",\n\"messageDetails\": \"Successfully Associated\",\n\"organizationId\": 1000830784,\n\"organizationName\": \"Pfizer\",\n\"emailDomains\": [\n\"@pfizer.com\",\n\"@gmail.com\"\n],\n\"parentDunsNumber\": \"879262386\",\n\"cdcId\": \"49f5b88e036d46f38e05ce260aeaeb2a\",\n\"isUserActive\": true,\n\"associatedDateTime\": 1674467158154,\n\"associatedBy\": \"01bdd9a4a21345929b7fa06acd3c53d5\"\n}",
  "Timestamp" : "2023-02-01T05:32:30.825Z",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:956978673417:de-eec-org-group-association-info.fifo:e986e954-6f3d-4309-b7c4-a4df2182227e"
}
```

Tried different way but it's not working , mostly the type of Message column is stringType need to change it in MapType and need to flatten the entire json file . Can anyone help?

Comment: Tried like below :

l=[]
l.append(i)
df = sc.parallelize(l).map(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
df = spark.read.json(df)

df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
Message:string
MessageId:string
SequenceNumber:string
Timestamp:string
TopicArn:string
Type:string
UnsubscribeURL:string


display(df)


But further conversion is not happening . Kindly help with UDF if possible .

Comment: Can you please share the output sample required

Comment: A dataframe with column values like :

"Type" : "Notification",
"MessageId" : "2bef84e1-39c1-5278-bb49-d8b2c22f6fbb",
"SequenceNumber" : "10000000000000012000",
"TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:956978673417:de-eec-org-group-association-info.fifo",
"messageType": "USER_ACTIVATION", 
"messageStatus": "SUCCESS",

Comment: "messageDetails": "Successfully Activated", 
"organizationId": 1000830784, 
"organizationName": "Pfizer", 
"parentDunsNumber": "879262386", 
"cdcId": "49f5b88e036d46f38e05ce260aeaeb2a", 
"isUserActive": true, 
"associatedDateTime": 1674667198154, 
"associatedBy": "01bdd9a4a21345929b7fa06acd3c53d5" 
"Timestamp" : "2023-02-01T05:33:34.242Z",
"UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:956978673417:de-eec-org-group-association-info.fifo:e986e954-6f3d-4309-b7c4-a4df2182227e"

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution with explode() function :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType, IntegerType, BooleanType
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

# Define the schema for the nested JSON
schema = StructType([
StructField("messageType", StringType()),
StructField("messageStatus", StringType()),
StructField("messageDetails", StringType()),
StructField("organizationId", IntegerType()),
StructField("organizationName", StringType()),
StructField("emailDomains", ArrayType(StringType())),
StructField("parentDunsNumber", StringType()),
StructField("cdcId", StringType()),
StructField("isUserActive", BooleanType()),
StructField("associatedDateTime", IntegerType()),
StructField("associatedBy", StringType())
])

df = spark.createDataFrame([input_json])
df_message = df.select("Message").select(from_json("Message", schema).alias("data"))
df_flat = df_message.select("data.*").select(explode("emailDomains").alias("emailDomains"))
df_result = df.join(df_flat, "MessageId", "left").drop("Message")
# Show the result
df_result.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the update , actually the structure of the json file is not fixed , can we get any dynamic script?